# $5$ red balls and $4$ blue balls into 3 boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Here is a question which was posted by someone and then deleted...

I have 5 red balls and 4 blue balls (assume balls have the same size). Divides balls into 3 different boxes, each box has 3 balls. What is the probability so that there is a least a box which 3 balls in it have the same color.

---

Here is how I solve it: We have a following possible configurations:
$$ 3r0b+0r3b+2r1b$$
$$ 3r0b+1r2b+1r2b$$
$$ 3r0b+2r1b+0r3b$$

---

$$ 2r1b+0r3b+3r0b$$
$$ 2r1b+1r2b+2r1b$$
$$ 2r1b+2r1b+1r2b$$
$$ 2r1b+3r0b+0r3b$$

---

$$ 1r2b+1r2b+3r0b$$
$$ 1r2b+2r1b+1r2b$$
$$ 1r2b+3r0b+1r2b$$

---

$$ 0r3b+2r1b+3r0b$$
$$ 0r3b+3r0b+2r1b$$

So there is 9 good configuration among 12 and thus the probability is $0,75$.

**Have I missed something? Is there quicker way?**

Comment: There are balls missing in the first configuration.

Comment: [The question has now been undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2779330/290189), but I think it's better to vote to close the original question, which lacks context, as a dupe of this question.  It's better to keep a more stable copy.

Comment: There are some solution now. And I still don't know which one is correct. Is this because of lack of probabilistic frame here. Nobody set a sample space and probabilistic function. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that since each box must have $3$ balls, a configuration is entirely determined by where you put the blue balls.

The stars and bars formula tells you that there are ${6\choose 2}=15$ ways to put the $4$ blue balls in three **labelled** boxes. Out of these $15$ ways, three are forbidden, where all blue balls are in the same box ($4$ balls in one box is too many). Therefore, $12$ configurations.

Out of these $12$ configurations, the only way to **not** have three balls of the same color in one box is to have at least one blue in every box (and not three in the same box, but this is automatic since there are four blue).

Once you have put a blue ball in each box (no choice to make here), your only choice is where to put the last one, there are $3$ options. Therefore **three out of twelve** configurations do not have one box with all balls of the same color.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianF You're welcome!

Comment: I agree that there are $12$ configurations by the way you count, but I don't think they are equally likely.

Comment: Equally likely configurations is implicit whenever nothing else is specified. Otherwise you could make up any probability space as you wish and get a different result.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Which process produces each of your configurations with the same probability? Arranging all the balls in a uniformly random sequence and putting the first three in one box, the next tree in the next box, and the last three in the last box _does not_ give the probabilities you claim.

Comment: Like I said, it's implicit in this kind of exercise. It may not seem natural to you, but if there were placeholders inside the boxes, it would have to be said. A configuration is a simultaneous choice of what lies in each box, period.

Comment: Try simulating a simpler case: Two red and two blue balls go into two two-ball boxes. You will find that "each box has one red and one blue ball" comes out half of the time, rather than the $1/3$ your reasoning would lead to.

Comment: Yes, the answer is $1/3$. It would be $1/2$ if the boxes were undistinguishable, but the question states "**different** boxes".

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: How would the balls know whether you're going to distinguish between the boxes afterwards?

Comment: The balls don't know. You do.

Comment: You know very well that there is no random mechanism supported by Occam's razor (to which we have to appeal here) that would make your $12$ configurations equally likely. @HenningMakholm 's solution does not presuppose numbered seats in the boxes, but that the balls are in an envelope when they are put in the boxes.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I am not saying that there is an underlying random mechanism, maybe that's where we have a misunderstanding here. What I am saying is that this phrasing implies that the configurations are equally likely, no matter how artificial this may seem from practical points of view. This is the way of thinking that I have been taught, that seems more natural to me, and that I teach, although I myself try as much as possible to avoid ambiguity in the phrasing of questions, by specifying probability spaces / indicating what is supposed to be equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

I can't easily convince myself that each of your configurations is equally likely, so it seems to be easier to imagine that each box has 3 *distinguishable* positions for balls.

Then there are $\binom 95=126$ configurations all in all.

Of these $3\cdot \binom 62=45$ have a box with three red balls.

If there's a box with three blue balls, then there must also be one with three red balls (there are not enough blue balls left over to put one in each of the two remaining boxes), so we have already counted all relevant configurations, and the probability we're after is
$$ \frac{45}{126} = \frac{5}{14}$$

Comment: I believe that equally likely configurations is implicit whenever nothing else is specified.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Does that mean you _don't_ think my 126 configurations are equally likely? Where is something else specified, then?

Comment: There are no placeholders in the boxes, you made them up.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Why should it give different probabilities to put the balls into the boxes one by one?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you put them one by one. only the final configuration matters.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: If it does not matter that we put them in one by one (which I agree to), then we get the probabilties I compute.

Comment: No, because only the final result matters. Look, I've been teaching probability only for a couple of years, so you may want to ask someone more experienced.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: If you have been teaching probability wrong for a couple of years, that doesn't make it more right. With your argument, you could do an experiment "throw ten fair coins and count the heads" and conclude that each of the $11$ possible answer outcomes should be equally likely because "only the final result matters".

Comment: The difference between the two settings lies in the assumptions that are implicitly made. You can't compute probabilities without a probability space, and this is commonly implicitly specified. In the OP, the (implicit) assumption is that all configurations are equally likely because nothing else is specified. When you deal with several coins, however, the assumption (again, completely implicit!) is that they are all independent and with probability space $1/2$ H, $1/2$ T. Which of course doesn't yield $11$ equally likely outcomes.

Comment: I understand that it may be disturbing that very often the probability space is implicit, but that is unfortunately the case. Personally I do my best when I write questions to avoid ambiguity, because it does feel unfair to those who are not used to it at the beginning.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: When you deal with balls the default assumption is that you have the balls in some kind of container, pick them out by a process that does not distinguish between the balls, and then assign each of the $n!$ equally likely arrangements of all your balls to one of the outcomes. That standard model does not produce your probabilties.

Comment: No, this is not the default assumption. We're going nowhere; like I said, ask someone else.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: That the probability space is left implicit does not mean that you can just decide to use a different probability space that the one that is ALWAYS IMPLICITLY ASSUMED for problems about balls and urns. Unless the problem _explicitly_ tells you to use a nonstandard probability space, which this one doesn't.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I get the same aswer as you, via a different approach that uses $1680$ as the starting point for the denominator instead of $126$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  A new user who does not have sufficient reputation to comment did not understand how you obtained your answer and has posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780143/5-red-balls-and-4-blue-balls) about it.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same answer as Henning Makholm, but by a different approach.  I imagine starting with the nine balls in a bag, reaching in to grab three that go into the first box, again to grab another three to go into the second box, and then dumping the final three in the third box.

To analyze this, it's convenient to *number* the nine balls, with 1-4 for the blue balls and 5-9 for the red ones.  If you do, there are

$${9\choose3}{6\choose3}{3\choose3}=84\cdot20\cdot1=1680$$

assignments in total (unlike Henning's $126$).

Next, it's convenient to count the number of assignments that *don't* have any boxes with a single color -- which is to say, the number of assignments in which one box has two blue balls and the other two have one blue ball each. This is each to do. The answer is

$$3\cdot{4\choose2}\cdot2\cdot5\cdot{4\choose2}=1080$$

That is, pick which of the $3$ boxes gets two blue balls, then choose $2$ of the $4$ blue balls to go in it, then pick which of the remaining $2$ blue balls goes in the first (say leftmost) box that's still empty, putting the other remaining blue ball in the other empty box, then pick one of the $5$ red balls to go in the box with the pair of blue balls, then choose $2$ of the remaining $4$ red balls to go with the first (leftmost) of the remaining boxes, with the other two going into the other.

The desired probability is thus

$$1-{1080\over1680}=1-{9\over14}={5\over14}$$

Comment: Hmm, and what would be result if balls are not the same (size)?

Comment: Should I post this as another question?

Answer (score 1):

We can treat the balls of the same color as being distinct (distinguishing them by shade or size or by placing labels on each ball).

Our sample space consist of all selections in which three balls are placed in each box.  There are $\binom{9}{3}$ ways to select which three balls are placed in the first box, $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to select which three of the remaining six balls are placed in the second box, and $\binom{3}{3}$ ways to place the remaining three balls in the third box.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$
ways to distribute the nine balls in such a way that three balls are placed in each box.

There are two ways to distribute the balls so that at least one box is filled with balls of the same color:

1. Three red balls are placed in one box, three blue balls are placed in a different box, and the remaining three balls are placed in the other box.
2. Three red balls are placed in one box and one red and two blue balls are placed in each of the other two boxes.

*Three red balls are placed in one box, three blue balls are placed in a different box, and the remaining three balls are placed in the other box*:  Choose which of the three boxes will receive three red balls, choose three of the five red balls to go in that box, choose which of the two remaining boxes will receive three blue balls, and choose which three of the four blue balls will go in that box.  The remaining balls must be placed in the other box.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{3}$$
such distributions.

*Three red balls are placed in one box and one red and two blue balls are placed in each of the other boxes*:  Choose which of the three boxes receives three red balls, choose which three of the five red balls go in that box, choose which one of the two remaining red balls and which two of the four blue balls go in the leftmost empty box.  The remaining balls must go in the remaining box.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$
such distributions.

Hence, the number of favorable cases is 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{3} + \binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$
Therefore, the probability that there is a box that contains three balls of the same color when five red and four blue balls are distributed to three distinct boxes in such a way that three balls are placed in each box is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{4}{3} + \dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{9}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{3}{3}} = \frac{600}{1680} = \frac{5}{14}$$
which agrees with the result obtained by both Barry Cipra and Henning Makholm.

Comment: So there is no difference if the balls are different.

Comment: If we wish to count equally likely distributions, it makes sense to treat the balls as if  they are different even when they are indistinguishable.  Consider the probability of rolling a $7$ when two identical dice are thrown.  There are $\binom{6}{2} + \binom{6}{1} = 21$ possible outcomes in the sample space, but they are not equally likely since each outcome with two different numbers can occur in two ways but a double can only occur in one way.   We instead count the $6^2 = 2\binom{6}{2} + \binom{6}{1}$ equally likely ordered pairs in our sample space and the six ordered pairs with sum $7$.

Comment: Thanks!.........